# how to check if edittext is single line android

Tags: android-edittext

I am making a custom android keyboard. I want to make it sure that when user press enter key proper EditorAction took place. Therefore I want to know is there any way to check if edittext is single line or not? Or is there any way to check min and max lines of editext?

Answer (score 1):

In your `onStartInput(EditorInfo info)` and `onStartInputView(EditorInfo info)` callbacks EditorInfo is passed in.

To check if it's a multiline you can do:

```
if (0 != (info.inputType & InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE)) {
   //This is multiline text field
}
```

[See TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it by setting a key listener and and checking getMaxLines() and getMinLines() properties. Note that it is applied for API > 15!

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this);

editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent)
    {
        if (view instanceof EditText && ((EditText) view).getMaxLines() == 1 && ((EditText) view).getMinLines() == 1)
        {
            // this is a single line EditText view
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```